# Join multiple table columns to multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

It's been years since I've used SSRS and SQL, so I apologize in advance for this remedial and poorly worded question.

I have a table, Incidents, which includes 2 columns, opener and owner (both integers).  These columns relate to a User table, from which I want to retrieve the user name.  I'm able to join the tables, but how do I go about retrieving the username as the opener and owner so that I can include it in my report?

```
SELECT
    TST_INCIDENT.OPENER_ID AS Logged_By,
    TST_INCIDENT.OWNER_ID AS Assignee,
    TST_INCIDENT.INCIDENT_ID AS Defect_ID,
    TST_INCIDENT.NAME AS Defect_Title,
    TST_INCIDENT.DESCRIPTION AS Defect_Desc,
    TST_USER.USER_NAME
FROM
    TST_USER
INNER JOIN 
    TST_INCIDENT ON TST_USER.USER_ID = TST_INCIDENT.OPENER_ID 
                 AND TST_USER.USER_ID = TST_INCIDENT.OWNER_ID
```

Comment: what is the issues ? please provide sample data  and ddl statements to work on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would join the user table once for each ID. Change them to left joins if the ID's can be missing.

```
SELECT
  TST_INCIDENT.OPENER_ID AS Logged_By
  ,TST_INCIDENT.OWNER_ID AS Assignee
  ,TST_INCIDENT.INCIDENT_ID AS Defect_ID
  ,TST_INCIDENT.NAME AS Defect_Title
  ,TST_INCIDENT.DESCRIPTION AS Defect_Desc
  ,A.USER_NAME as OPENER_USER_NAME
  ,B.USER_NAME as OWNER_USER_NAME
FROM TST_INCIDENT
INNER JOIN TST_USER A ON A.USER_ID = TST_INCIDENT.OPENER_ID 
INNER JOIN TST_USER B ON B.USER_ID = TST_INCIDENT.OWNER_ID
```

Comment: Good grief, that was too simple.  As soon as saw the select, it jogged my memory.  Thank you so much!